# How to detect a couple of pings transmitted from a virtual machine to another by using Snort, which is integrated in AlienVault?

Tags: snort, alienvault

For the record: I did the following instruction (found them on a website)

1. I enabled snort sensors (`snort_syslog` and `snortunified`).
2. In alienvault: `~# nano /etc/snort/rules/local.rules`
3. I did the following rule

   ```
   alert icmp 192.168.1.130 192.168.1.120 -> any any
   (msg:"blablabla"; sid:1000004)
   ```
4. Save and exit
5. After that I did:

   ```
   alienvault:~# perl /usr/share/ossim/scripts/create_sidmap.pl /etc/snort/rules/
   ```
6. `alienvault:~# /etc/init.d/ossim-server restart`

For some reasons nothing happens in AlienVault interface in SIEM when I ping `192.168.1.120` from `192.168.1.130`.

#### Any ideas??

Comment: This might be my favorite SO question title yet.  We programmers must sound like crazy people to non-techies...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether it is still relevant but in my opinion there is a mistake in your Snort rule:

The rule in Snort cannot consist of two IP-adresses in the first part of the rule header.
At the point where you declared the IP '**192.168.1.120**' you have to declare a **port**.

The solution you need looks like the following (if i get you right):

*alert icmp 192.168.120 any -> 192.168.1.130 any (msg:"blablabla"; sid:**1000004**)*

And also the other way:

*alert icmp 192.168.1.130 any -> 192.168.1.120 any (msg:"blablabla"; sid:**1000005**)*

For writing rules in the correct syntax take a look at the manual of snort: http://manual.snort.org/node29.html#SECTION00423000000000000000

I hope that this can help you.

/Chris